# how to use SharedPreferences to pass data from activity to another activity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i'm trying to pass my data from first activity to another activity say it fourth activity. i'm using the code on `onClick` for button in first activity where the data comes from and also in `onclick` button in fourth activity  when the data want to pass from first activity. but it wont work. it just pass the 0 data which is i set it for default. please help

this is `SharedPreferences` code in my first activity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("user_id", user_id);
editor.putString("username", usernameJ);
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.putString("email", email);
editor.apply();
```

and this is `SharedPreferences` code in my four activity:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
user_id = sharedPreferences.getInt("user_id", 0);
new UbahLapor().execute();
```

Comment: Your code looks (basically) fine to me.  Are you certain that those variables have values when you assign them to shared preferences in your first activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty this

**First if you store data using shared preference then try:**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
editor.putString("username", username);
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.apply();
```

**get data using shared preference**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
username= sharedPreferences.getString("username", null);
```

**Second you pass the data first activity to another activity using intent then try:**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activityClass);
    intent.putExtra("message", text);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

**get the data using intent**

```
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    success_msg_txt.setText(intent.getStringExtra("message"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`editor.apply()` does the work in a thread (asynchronous), So it might take time.

**so try**

```
 editor.apply();
```

instance of

```
 editor.commit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your preferences this way (provided that `user_id`, `username`, `name` and `email` have already been declared and assigned values):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
editor.putInt("user_id", user_id);
editor.putString("username", usernameJ);
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.putString("email", email);
editor.apply();
```

and read it back:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
user_id = sharedPreferences.getInt("user_id", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [editor.commit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#commit()) instead of [editor.apply()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply()).

apply() updates your sharedprefernces asynchronously.
commit() updates your sharedprefernces synchronously. Note that commit() is a blocking call.